# jquery ajax call back request bringing html from php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making an ajax request where I will type name in input box to search data from db, It's working fine,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {

    var nameVar = $('input#name').val();        
    if($.trim(nameVar) != ''){
        $.post('records.php', {name: nameVar}, function(data){
        $('div#name-data').text(data);
});    
    }    
});
});

</script>

----php

if(isset($_POST['name'])){    
$name = $_POST['name'];     
echo $name;
```

Now the problem is when I embed the html into php and echo it, It prints the html also

```
echo  "<div class='tblDiv'>";
echo  "</div>";

result: <div class='tblDiv'> Name </div>
```

how to avoid that and get the result in style?

Comment: What you have is the behaviour from AJAX - especially jQuery, anything printed (**including html**) in the php script will be parsed and returned by the AJAX. To get only certain data, split up your php script into parts, style, html etc.

Comment: i got that thank you friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
 $('#name-data').html(data);
```

`.text()` will not parse the `html` content, it will escape the `html` and print the passed value as it is

Comment: @JeroenBellemans depends on how the function should react if called again